# phpMyAdmin 4.5.0.2 shows blank page with Firefox 40.0.3

Tags: php, mysql, firefox, nginx, phpmyadmin

Oracle 7
Nginx
PHP5.5

I am currently getting only a blank page when trying to access phpMyAdmin instance. I've already took look at the page source and there is HTML content but for whatever reason, the page remains blank. Is this a bug? Has anyone experienced this particular issue like this before?

http://pastebin.com/bDQ2p52b

Comment: Clear your cache and cookies then try again.

Comment: First thing I did before I asked. Cache was cleaned and all cookies were removed

Comment: Beyond that I am not sure you're going to get much help on SO for this, as it's off topic. You might try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/ "Questions directly related to phpMyAdmin should be asked on stackoverflow. ". That's why I asked here. I'll ask on serverfault as well.

Comment: From that same page; **Questions about server issues (web server configuration, "404 - Not Found" error, etc), should be asked on serverfault.com.** It's not a problem with using phpMyAdmin, it a problem with your installation of it.

Comment: Not having server issues here. This seem to be common problem with PMA when I look at bug reports.

Comment: Any hint in the web server's error log?

Comment: @MarcDelisle Yeah, when I increased the error loging, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this issue by:

a) Enabling $cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;

b) Remove the hide class from libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php on line 171

Although I recieved a login form, however it didn't resolve the underlying issue, as certian objects on the page were inoperable. Digging into the source page; I discoververed that js/get_scripts.js.php output was being trancuated. I did some researched online and landed on https://serverfault.com/questions/269173/why-is-the-response-truncated-at-16k-with-php-fastcgi, checked my fastcgi_temp_path and noticed that the ownership was set improperly on /var/lib/nginx/tmp. This resolved all the issues I was having earlier.